# Drive based app with client side file download

Tags: google-drive-api

I am building an android app which needs file download using drive. Is it a good practice / feasible to keep the file download in my android app rather than my API server ? I am planning to have an API in my server to generate the drive token using credentials and sending token to android app and downloading the file using this token. Is this possible to generate token in server and use it in android app ( My client ) ? I am planning to avoid downloading of file in my API server which is unnecessary.

Comment: Try to check the [Drive Android API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro) for the things that you can only do with the API. There's a sample code there that you can follow.

Comment: I can use API. Can the authentication done on server side and pass token ? I don't want to put the main account credentials in client side.